# Text using image sprite and CSS

Tags: html, css

Is is possible to use an image sprite for text on a webpage using CSS?

[image: font.gif]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        p { background-image: url('font.gif') }
        p 'character' { width: 4px; height: 5px }
        p 'a' { background-position: 0 0 }
        p 'b' { background-position: -6px 0 }
        p 'c' { background-position: -10px 0 }
        etc...
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is some test text. It doesn't mean anything.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use p.character, p.a, p.b like this and call like this <p class="a"></p>

Comment: Sorry I know it's not proper syntax — I was trying to illustrate my question so it could be better understood. I'm not sure what you're suggesting by using a class for a single letter on the whole paragraph of text. Unless there's a way to target individual characters within a paragraph through the class on the p element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use graphics for text in this way, but try this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p { background-image: url('font.gif');width: 4px; height:5px;display:inline-block;}
    p .A { background-position: 0 0 }
    p .B { background-position: -6px 0 }
    p .C { background-position: -10px 0 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="C"></p><p class="A"></p><p class="B"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not going to say this isn't a good solution based on what I asked (although paragraphs are block elements so this would be creating vertical text) but I'm looking for something that doesn't require having to wrap each individual letter in an element, unless there was a way to do so dynamically? I'd really like to avoid making a mess of everything.

Comment: Then you'll have to make words instead of letters and use that. As for dynamic, you can use PHP GD functions to create an image with custom text in it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think using javascript to manipulate the text is a good idea.


<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            span {
                background-image: url('font.gif');
                display: inline-block;
                width: 10px;
                height: 14px;
            }
            .a {
                background-position: 0 0
            }

            .b {
                background-position: -6px 0
            }

            .c {
                background-position: -10px 0
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="text">This is some test text. It doesn't mean anything.</p>
    </body>
    <script>
        var p = $("#text");
        var text = p.text();
        p.html('');
        for (var i in text) {
            p.append('<span class="' + text[i] + '"></span>');
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I don't know why would you do so, if you just want change the font, you can use
@font-face,like

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family:myfont;
    src:url(font.ttf);
}

* {
    font-family:myfont;
}

</style>
```